# What framework Google, Microsoft, FB use to document their REST APIs

Tags: rest, documentation, spring-restdocs

I am using Swagger for REST API documentation which is built using Spring Framework. I am looking for better alternatives where I don't need to define complex resources again and again in every API.

Like Google has a well-defined documentation [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/changes/get). What frameworks top IT companies using for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have advised two of those companies to use OPTIONS.

OPTIONS data can be cached at runtime giving a custom APIDOC per each ROLE/AUTHORITY.

That way USER will not see ADMIN endpoints and you can create a dynamic APIDOC.